# Do I need to solder for activating PCB antenna on this ESP32

Tags: antenna, esp32, pcb-antenna

I designed and ordered a PCB with ESP32. I want to use the PCB antenna, but this has two options (1. PCB antenna 2. Connector for antenna). I am not sure if I need to solder something to activate the PCB antenna. I cannot program it yet because, some circuitry is missing to program it.

[image: ESP 32 Module on my custom PCB]

Comment: If you designed it, then I suppose you're the only one who should know.

Comment: @marko pretty sure they meant they designed a carrier board for this module not the module itself.

Comment: Yes @marko is right. I mean to say I designed a PCB that uses esp32 board

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the jumper is there to select either the PCB antenna or the UFL connector.

As we can see from the image in red, the default is the UFL connector as there is a 0R resistor connecting the two pads. If you wish to use an external antenna then you are all set.

Alternatively, if you wish to use the on-board antenna, by the looks of it you remove the 0R resistor joining the middle and lower two pads as shown below in blue, and then reinstall connecting middle and upper pads (or short with a solder bridge) as shown in green to connect the PCB antenna.

[image: Antenna Selection Jumper]

Comment: Just to supplement the answer: the schematics can be found [here](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wrover-b_datasheet_en.pdf). The difference between the "B" and "IB" modules is in the R14, R15 resistors.